# Dependencies on cutil when using CUDA 5.0

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

When I run the `make` command to complie a CUDA program under Linux 64bits, I receive the following error message:

```
    error: cutil.h: No such file or directory
```

I found some answers, but none of them useful.

In the `makefile`, there is one `CUDA_SDK_PATH`, but cannot find anything useful about the SDK in the CUDA Getting Started Guide:
http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html

*How should i set to the `CUDA-SDK-PATH`?*

Comment: What version of CUDA are you using?

Comment: @talonmies  cuda 5.0, and the install path is "/usr/local/cuda-5.0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are planning on using CUDA 5 or later, it be necessary to modify the code you are trying compile to remove or replace dependencies on `libcutil`. That was an unofficial component of the CUDA SDK in version 4 and earlier and has been deprecated and removed from CUDA 5.

The alternative would be to build the code with CUDA 4.2 or to try building the library from the CUDA 4.2 SDK source using the CUDA 5 toolchain. I have no personal experience with the latter and don't know whether it is feasible or not.