# CUDA C - library error from cutil.h to helper_cuda.h

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I have a project developed in C, on CUDA 4.0. Now i try to compile it on CUDA 5.0 but i have some problem with cutil.h, i have changed cutil to helper_cuda.h and i receive this error always:

```
In file included from /path/to/helper_cuda.h:24
```

and

```
/path/to/helper_string.h:18: fatal error: fstream: No such file or directory
```

fstream is a C++ library, how i can compile this without have this error?

Sorry for my english :D

Comment: If it is a C++ library, you will not be able to use it with C. They are different languages.

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. Have you taken a look at the following posts: [CUDA cutil.h where is it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024453/cuda-cutil-h-where-is-it), [CUDA 5.0: Replacement for cutil.h?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284961/cuda-5-0-replacement-for-cutil-h), and [Dependencies on cutil when using CUDA 5.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17670278/dependencies-on-cutil-when-using-cuda-5-0)?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

1. Load the CUDA 4.0 SDK on your CUDA 5.0 setup
2. Build the CUDA 4.0 SDK using the CUDA 5 toolkit (nvcc, etc.)
3. Now include the same header files and link against the same libraries (that you just built) that correspond to the `cutil` arrangement from the CUDA 4.0 SDK.

`helper_cuda.h` is not a drop-in replacement for `cutil.h` as you are discovering.  Very likely, if you worked past this `fstream` issue, you might run into another one, depending on what components out of the `cutil` project you are actually using.